# How can I have variables with dynamic names in Python

Tags: arrays, dynamic, python-2.7, filenames

I am new to Python and I am looking to implement the feature of dynamic name for variables and arrays. For example,  I would like to have 10 arrays such as this with different names
`Array=[0 for i in range(10)]`

Comment: @Gary It's possible, it's just a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous posts, it's not a good idea. Still, here's a way to do it

```
N = 3
code = ','.join(["Array"+str(n) for n in range(N)]) + " = " + ','.join(["[]" for n in range(N)])
exec code
```

Comment: Thanks 
Then how can assign a value for example to Array01